# Am I complaining too much to Allah? How can I stop this?

Tags: practical-islam, allah, sin, forgiveness

For any bad or mishap I complain to Allah a lot. It feels like I am pissed and just blaming him for everything. But just after that I feel bad and start doing Istigfar.

I wanted his help, though I always need his help but that day I felt very bad due to some bad events. And I started to feel like my Allah is leaving me alone. I felt scared. I started to complain even more.

I just wanted to know if at some point most of us complain to Allah. Am I gonna get mercy from him for my nonsense complains?

Thank you.

Comment: It's said in the Quran :  do not despair of the mercy of Allah.(39:53). Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 1):

My dear brother in Islam, by the mercy of Allah, I happened to stumble upon your concern & may I answer your trouble with the most justice.

As humans, we are ungrateful to our Lords.

It is unfair that you are taking out your frustrations to Allah, about Allah, when it is you who have wronged yourself.

Allah loves to hear from you, he wants you to come closer to him & instead of complaining about what he didnt do for you, perhaps you should complain about yourself, what is it that Allah commanded you to do & out of your own weakness, you faultered.

Our beloved prophet pbuh was free from sins & yet he always seeked forgiveness from Allah.

Allah is testing you, he doesnt want to make you miserable, because as human beings, we do a good job at making ourselves miserable & Allah promises a miserable life for those who disobeys him, so establish prayer, protect your prayer & do righteous good deeds.

Know that Allah loves you, he wants what is best for you & whatever is going on in your life, it is only temporary & no days are the same, so have hope, have faith in Allah & know that Allah is with the patient.

The one thing you want to consider is how you can change the condition of your heart, because a true believer needs to return back to Allah with a sound heart, so ask yourself honestly, what is the condition of your heart right now & instead of complaining, do something about it that is within your own control.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior of yours is due to your mental and intellectual turmoil. And it hurts you more than anything. Maybe this is exactly why such behavior is sinful. That you suffer yourself and see the cause of the problems as a very big cause far from your will, so you behave passively and weakly towards the problems. This thinking will cause you a lot more harm. This means that you have given great shadows to the possibly small misfortunes.
I myself have spent these days and fortunately I was able to reach some intellectual maturity.

There are several categories of life difficulties. Some hardships are the result of our actions and some are divine tests. But all hardships are useful for strengthening our minds and spirits.
You should know that humans were created in hardship. This is an explicit verse of the Qur'an. So hardship is an integral part of life.
Some difficulties are the direct or indirect impact of our own behavior and choices. It is the result of one's own actions to drive recklessly if one has an accident. That we eat harmful fast foods, sugary drinks, etc., regardless of the divine commandments, will surely make us sick and disabled. It is our own fault.
In one verse of the Qur'an it says, "After every hardship it is easy, and surely, after every hardship it is easy." This is good news for you to be sure it will come easy after any hardship. You will be given a chance to breathe to prepare for the next difficulty.

In another verse, God assures His servants that:
Whoever is wary of Allah, He shall make for him a way out [of the adversities of the world and the Hereafter] and provide for him from whence he does not count upon. And whoever puts his trust in Allah, He will suffice him. Indeed Allah carries through His commands. Certainly, Allah has ordained a measure [and extent] for everything.
It is a solution to problems. It is like a sedative and gives all the servants a strange reassurance. I have installed this on the wall of my house so that it is always in front of my eyes.